# JavaScript Odd Number Sorter Coding Challenge

Tags: javascript

Ok so I'm working on learning JavaScript and I came across a Coding Challenge question which I can not solve. It gives me the outline/skeleton of the format I should use and wants me to find the odd numbers from 1-5000.

> Starting with the basic function given below, write a function called sumOddNumbers that will print to the console and return the sum of all the odd numbers from 1 to 5000.  Consider using a loop, and don't forget to call the function afterwards!
>
> ~ Format ~
>
> ```
> function sumOddNumbers() {
>     var sum = 0;
>
>     // Your code here
>
>     console.log(sum);
>     return sum;
> }
> ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What code have you tried, and what difficulties have you encountered? For tips on asking a question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a loop:

```js
console.log(5000**2/4);
```

If 5000 is a dynamic input to your function, then the formula is as follows:

```js
function sumOddNumbers(n) {
     return (n + n%2)**2/4;
}
console.log(sumOddNumbers(5000));
```

If really it has to be done with a loop, and according to the template (which is not very nice BTW):

```js
function sumOddNumbers() {
     var sum = 0;
     for (let i = 1; i <= 5000; i+=2) {
         sum += i;
     } 
     console.log(sum);
     return sum;
}
sumOddNumbers();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < 5000; i += 2) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumOddNumbers(max) { 
  let sum = 0;

  for(let i = 1; i <= max; i+=2){
    sum += i;
  }

  console.log(sum);
  return sum;
}

sumOddNumbers(5000);
```